# Intel XDK legacy Build Problam

Tags: plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk, legacy-app

In new version of intel xdk they removed legacy build option and now only showing cordova hybrid build option which not good because apk easily convertible  to zip it is showing complete source code in asset folder to protect from it ,i want to use cordova-plugin-crypt-file (https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file) plugin in intel xdk to protect complete source code how can i use this plugin if anybody have any link or suggestion or any other way to solve problem so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In updated Intel xdk ,they remove legacy build option.But in the updated intel xdk you can build normal application and [cross Walk](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/blog/what-is-crosswalk) application.Also the above mentioned plugin work on crosswalk , android and ios.

Comment: i have done as you say but problem remain so please convert intel xdk apk to zip and see in asset complete source code are there.